# How to expose different GET routes for the same entity

Tags: api-platform.com, symfony5

I'm using Symfony for the backend and API-Platform. I have an entity User like this :

```
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 */
#[ApiResource(
    itemOperations: [
        'get' => [
            'normalization_context' => ['groups' => ['user:read']],
        ],
    ],
)]
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private int $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     */
    #[Groups(['user:read'])]
    private string $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    #[Groups(['user:read'])]
    private string $firstname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    #[Groups(['user:read'])]
    private string $lastname;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Project::class, mappedBy="user", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    #[Groups(['user:read'])]
    private Collection $foo;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=MediaObject::class, cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    #[ApiProperty(iri: 'http://schema.org/image')]
    #[Groups(['user:read'])]
    private ?MediaObject $picture1;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=MediaObject::class, cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    #[ApiProperty(iri: 'http://schema.org/image')]
    #[Groups(['user:read'])]
    private ?MediaObject $picture2;
}
```

For the moment, I have one GET route for an item : /api/users/{id}
I would like to have 3 GET routes for an item :

- /api/users/{id}/data where I would have email, firstname and lastname
- /api/users/{id}/foo where I would have foo
- /api/users/{id}/pictures
  where I would have picture1 and picture2

Is it possible and if so, how could this be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is explained [here](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/controllers/#creating-custom-operations-and-controllers).

You have to do something like that:

```php
#[ApiResource(
    itemOperations: [
        'get' => [
            'normalization_context' => ['groups' => ['user:read']],
        ],
        'get_data' => [
            'method' => 'get',
            'path' => '/api/users/{id}/data',
            'normalization_context' => [
                'user:read:data'
            ]
        ],
    ],
)]
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     */
    #[Groups(['user:read', 'user:read:data'])]
    private string $email;

    //  ...
```

Comment: Thanks : it works just fine ! I was searching complexity where the answer was so simple... Thank you very much !